# Is it possible to create a logo for your web application for Windows Phone, just like for iOS?

Tags: mobile

We can create logos and have iOS and Android recognize these by using

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="image.png" />
```

Is there a way to create a logo and include it so that it can be used in Windows Phone as well?

Answer (score 2):

The `apple-touch-icon` and `apple-touch-icon-precomposed` are quasi-variants of the favicon concept.

There doesn't appear to be any Windows Mobile-specific equivalent at this time.

Comment: Not for Windows Phone, but Windows 7 does support [pinned sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491731%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which is similar in concept and just uses [the favicon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: (I don't have an emulator to test on at this workstation) but I was going to guess that it pulls the favicon. One plus is that you can use a decently-sized image for favicons, and aren't necessarily restricted to the antiquated 32x32 favicon.ico files :)